# perl print only the last line of the array

Tags: perl

I am trying to print the array but the out put contain only the last line of the array. the partial code is as follow.

```
open OUT, "> /myFile.txt"
    or die "Couldn't open output file: $!";

foreach (@result) {

    print OUT;
}
```

the out put is

```
List Z
```

which is the last line, but when I do `print "@result"` the out put is

```
List A

List B

List C  so on...
```

I am little bit confuse why the results are different on the same array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is here

```
open OUT, "> /myFile.txt"
```

this should be

```
open OUT, ">>", "/myfile.txt"
```

What you wrote overwrites the entire file for each iteration of the foreach(@result) loop.
What you are intending to do is append to it (">>").
">>" appends, ">" overwrites.

Also take note of how i broke ">> /myfile.txt" into ">>", "/myfile.txt".
This is both more secure, and more robust for less specific applications of open.

Comment: very..very interesting...that's it. solved! thank you so very much.

Comment: This would be the correct diagnosis if the `open` statement was inside the for-loop. If it is, then the correct solution is to move the open statement outside, not by using append mode for each iteration.

Comment: TLP, you are right. I have a feeling the open statement is nested within an even larger block, and he is expecting each iteration of that larger block to print out a different list he has stored in @result.  Thank you for showing me where I was wrong, TLP. :)

Answer (score 7):

Working on a hunch, I tried adding `\r` to the end of your input lines, and sure enough, it creates the illusion that only the last line of your input is printed to the file. Here's the code to test it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @result = map "$_\r", 'A' .. 'Z';

open (OUT, "> myFile.txt") or die("Couldn't open output file: $!");
foreach (@result) {
    print OUT ;
}
```

What you have probably done is performed `chomp` on lines from a file from a different operating system (DOS, Windows), which does not strip the `\r` line endings. Hence, when the lines are printed, the lines overwrite each other.

If this is what is wrong, the solution is to use the `dos2unix` tool to fix your files, or to use:

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

to strip your newlines.

You may inspect your input by using the [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) module, using the option `Useqq`, e.g.:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper \@result;
```

If these whitespace characters are in your output, they will then be visible.

Comment: thanks, you nail the problem, the input came from webpage and has white-space character. I have tried to strip out per you suggestion but still the last line is printed.

Comment: Did you try printing the lines with Data::Dumper to see the whitespace?

Comment: yes Sir, printed like this `$VAR1 = [ "list\t200\r\n", undef ];`

Comment: Then you didnt try `s/\s+\z//` because those chars would have been stripped then.

Comment: I did `foreach (@result) {
        s/\s+\z//;
     print Dumper \@result;` and the result came with this modification

Comment: Well that particular loop doesn't strip whitespace. `s/\s+\z// for @result; print Dumper \@result`.

Comment: Oh, it does work. This is basic perl code. Its definitely your line endings, and my suggestion fixes line endings. If it does not work, you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign line terminators from any platform can easily be fixed by clearing whitespace from the end of the line and adding it back when printing it

Like this

```
open my $out, '>', '/myFile.txt' or die "Couldn't open output file: $!";

foreach (@result) {
  s/\s+$//;
  print $out "$_\n";
}
```

or

```
foreach my $line (@result) {
  $line =~ s/\s+$//;
  print $out "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks much,I have used your suggestion but still the problem didn't go.

Comment: I can't imagine why. The substitution will remove all carriage returns and linefeeds from the end of the string. If you have used a different variable for the loop then you need to use that explicitly in the substitution. I have added to my answer to demonstrate this